# How to format an erlang float into an integer (without decimal point)

Tags: erlang

I need to produce a String that will be later printed and cannot have a decimal point in it. For that I am trying to use the io_lib:format module in Erlang, but I am uncertain of what is the appropriate format to achieve this.

For example, I can use the following up to the .1 precision, but not .0

```
io_lib:format("~.2f", [789.1234]).
789.12

io_lib:format("~.1f", [789.1234]).
789.1

io_lib:format("~.0f", [789.1234]).
** exception error: bad argument
 in function  io_lib:format/2
    called as io_lib:format("~.0f",[789.1234])
```

All I need is from:

- 789.1234 produce the string **"789"**
- 123.0 produce the string **"123"**

I know I can do a "re" replacement but I am trying to find a format-elegant way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
1> float_to_list(-223.56,[{decimals,0}]).
"-224"

2> float_to_list(223.56,[{decimals,0}]).
"224"

3> float_to_list(223.44456,[{decimals,0}]).
"223"

4> float_to_list(223.44456,[{decimals,6}]).        
"223.444560"

5> float_to_list(223.44456,[{decimals,6},compact]).       
"223.44456"
```

[`erlang:float_to_list/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#float_to_list-2)

Comment: I like this approach and function. Quite complete.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer for #1 be 223?

Answer (score 27):

If you truncate a float number in erlang it will become integer. Below is code.

```
1> is_float(round(1.5)).
false
2> is_integer(round(1.5)).
true 
3> is_float(trunc(1.5)).    
false
4> is_integer(trunc(1.5)).
true
5> round(1.5).            
2
6> trunc(1.5).            
1
```

Comment: `round(1.44445)` returns `1` in my environment (Erlang R16B) as well as on [Try Erlang](http://www.tryerlang.org) online REPL. I wouldn't rely upon this function. Ideone [seems to return](http://ideone.com/yppCjM) the same result.

Comment: @YasirArsanukaev: what should `round(1.44445)` return if not `1`?

Comment: I guess this would work, as producing a string out of it does not reveal any decimal point: io_lib:format("This is number ~p",[trunc(1.5)]).
[84,104,105,115,32,105,115,32,110,117,109,98,101,114,32,"1"]

Answer (score 0):

To convert to integer you can do :

```
erlang:list_to_integer(erlang:float_to_list(789.1234,[{decimals,0}])).
```

and if you want to keep as it is in string then

```
erlang:float_to_list(789.1234,[{decimals,0}]).
```